# google maps api autocomplete output places of a specific city

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need a code that can output only places related to a specific city of a country.In other words I need to find places within a radius/bounds.for Instance Sydney.the autocomplete code shows the places in Sydney only nothing else.

Thanks

Comment: SO is not a software writing service... You should to [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and show what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: @MegaTron hi..here is the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>

function initAutocomplete() {

  //5 mile bounds around orlando, fl 

  var streetLng = -81.43061;
  var streetLat = 28.56683;

  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(streetLat), parseInt(streetLng));
  var north = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, 5, 0).lat();
  var east = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, 5, 90).lng();
  var south = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, 5, 180).lat();
  var west = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, 5, -90).lng();
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(north, east), new google.maps.LatLng(south, west));

    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        componentRestrictions: { country: "us" }, types: ['address'], bounds: defaultBounds
    });
}

initAutocomplete();
```

Comment: please change the lat and lang for Sydney

Comment: output results shows all the places/cities in Australia..I've added library "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry" but didn't work....